# Understanding mathematical concept behind phase space and phase portait

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, potential, phase-space, differential-equations

I'd like to expose the problem through an example, which was what made me think about it. It's a rational mechanics problem.

Consider the one dimensional Cauchy problem $\begin{cases}m\ddot{x} = F(x,\dot{x},t) \\ x(0) = x_0 \\ \dot{x}(0) = v_0 \\\end{cases}$ where $F : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}, x,x_0,v_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, and suppose exists a potential $V$, i.e a function such that $-V'(x) = F(x)$.

With the last sentence we made sure to consider only purely positional forces and as a consequence, "purely positional potentials". From this we can introduce thec concept of phase space and phase portrait. What I don't get about this last one, is the following :

We started from the differential equation above, which has solutions that are scalar function that depends on time, i.e $x = x(t)$, but when we use $V$ (which is a function of $x$) to deal with phase portrait, seems like $x$ has become now an idependant variable, forgetting about time.

So my question is what mathematical concept is behind this type of study, what allows to do so, and why.

Comment: Why do you think $x$ became independent? You can still write $V(x(t))$ to make it clear that $x$ depends on $t$.

Comment: @NDewolf Yes, but what I'm trying to understand is that for example in a phase portrait, to study critical points, I differentiate the potential $V$ with respect to its variable $x$, not with respect to $t$ which would lead to a chain rule, although as you say $V = V(x(t))$.

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1 :** In think the easiest way to approach this is to notice that you can rewrite the Cauchy problem as a **first order** problem :
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{l} 
m\dot v = F(x,v,t) \\
\dot x = v \\
v(0) = v_0\\
x(0) = x_0
\end{array}\right.$$

Therefore, the evolution of the system depends only on his position in the $(x,v)$ plane. In classical mechanics, this is phase space : the space of initial configuration. A point in phase space uniquely determines the time-evolution of the system

---

**Step 2 :** to clear a confusion that appeared in the comment.

Let $z = (x,v)$ be the vector which represents the system in phase space. Then, we have :
$$\dot z = X(z)$$

where the vector field $X$ is defined by :
$$X(x,v) = (v,F(x,v,t))$$

Then, by studying the behavior of $X$ (as a function of $x,v$), we can deduce properties of the dynamics of $x(t),v(t)$. In mathematics, this is called the study of *ordinary differential equations* and *dynamical systems*.

For example, a fixed point of the system is a $z_0$ such that $X(z_0) = 0$. The derivative of $X$ at $z_0$ can inform us on whether this fixed point is stable or not.

---

**Step 3 :** In the case where $F(x,v,t) = -\nabla V(x)$, it is good to take the second variable to be $p = m\dot x$ rather that $v = \dot x$. Then, the differential equations are :
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\dot p = - \nabla_x V(x)\\
\dot x = p/m
\end{array}\right.$$

Notice then that this can be rewritten :
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\dot p = - \frac{\partial H}{\partial x}\\
\dot x = \frac{\partial H}{\partial p}
\end{array}\right.$$
where the function $H$, called the hamiltonian is :
$$H(x,p) = \frac{p^2}{2m} + V(x)$$

This is the starting point for *Hamiltonian mechanics*, and the vast mathematical theory which underlies it, *symplectic geometry*.

Comment: But this doesn't answer my question

Comment: Step 2 deals with the confusion that the same letter $x$ describes both the variable of the function $V(x)$ and the function of time $x(t)$. If this still doesn't answer your question, please make it clear what is missing.

Comment: This answer in the surface, I'd like to know where I can read something about what you cited as "studying the behavior of $X$ as function of $x,v$ we can deduce properties of the dynamics of $x(t),v(t)$. In particular passing from $x,v$ to $x(t),v(t)$. Any help or reference ?

Comment: Look up *ODEs* and *dynamical systems*, you will find many courses and books on free access.